# AngularJS: Get Scope of Dependent Module

Tags: angularjs, events, module, angularjs-scope, mediator

## Getting The Scope of Another Module to Dispatch Events;

## Acyclical Directed Communication Network

EDIT: THIS QUESTION IS UNDER REFORMATION.

### Intention

What I'm looking to do is fairly straight-forward. I have an Application Core module which looks like this:

```
var app, application = app = angular.module('app', ['session', 'validation', 'summary', 'participants', 'ngRoute']);
```

...where each dependency is a <s>**module with its own $rootScope**</s> (*SEE COMMENTS BELOW*).

**I intend on implementing a *Mediator*** -- ***not* an *EventHub***. EventHubs are simply a *skinny-waist* to which subsystems can publish and subscribe to *broadcast* channels *on a specific medium*. What I want is a true Mediator -- which, according to GoF, actually manages security of *how and where* modules communicate, in a *unicast* model.

That said, I cannot solely rely on using `$rootScope.$broadcast/$emit` as this will allow any & every module to listen to events from other modules -- without any control or intervention (mediation) from a centralized mechanism.

### Problem

The problem arises when there is one module firing an event, say, `'excuseFileLog'` and other listening for `'excuseFileLog'` -- while the mediator is listening to this event from one module and dispatching it for another. Mediator is listening for one module to say "please excuse the 'FileLog'" and telling another that "an excuseFile has been logged". This is very semantic, as *excuse*, *File*, and *Log* are each, both a verb and a noun. So when Mediator dispatches this same event that it, itself, is listening for -- we enter an Infinite Loop:

```
// mediator is the sole medium for channels
mediator.on('excuseFileLog', function(){
    mediator.fire('excuseFileLog');
});
```

### Solvent

Put simply, I need to be able to access each module's `$rootScope` and fire events on that module alone -- hopfully, without the need of creating a service that will have to be injected into every module; which will encumber the developer with having to remember to implement the service and creating slightly tighter coupling. If a service is involved, then I may as well implement my own mediator/eventing-system, as apposed to **leveraging Angular's eventing system**. As the rest of the team is somewhat novice, I would prefer to keep 'chores' to a minimum.

Any help is very appreciated :)

Comment: Unless you have done some special modification, each application has only a single `$rootScope`, not every module.

Comment: tesseKATT, You're definitely right... never noticed this. I guess what I really want is really to be able to 'forward' events outward from a receiver -- a broadcast OMITTING the listener who dispatched it. In addition, I realized I had still conflated some aspects b/w Mediator and EventHub. I will restructure my question soon, as I find its still very useful and would like to see some solutions to my particular problem. THANKS A TON FOR POINTING THIS OUT & HELPING THUS FAR :)